Connecting Power BI with ChargeBee API
I have the following code that connects me with Chargebee API, and it returns the correct data. However, I cant figure out how to get the whole dataset, as Chargebee only paginates 10 rows as standard. How can I adjust the code to paginate my whole dataset?
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://{COMPANY.NAME}.chargebee.com/api/v2/subscriptions")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded list" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "list"),
    #"Expanded list1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded list", "list", {"subscription", "customer"})
in
    #"Expanded list1"

I have tried through various LLM's and it has to do with some offsets that also returns in the data. However i cant seem to figure it out.

You can use the limit parameter in your API call but you can still fetch only 100 records at a time and you'll have to paginate post that.
Curious to know what your use case is! Are you planning to regularly sync data between Chargebee & Power BI?
